# Updated version of Facebook client for dotNetOpenAuth

Tags: .net, upgrade, dotnetopenauth

I upgraded to the newest version of DotNetOpenAuth and I was using the "DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock" which has facebook in it.

However it does not compile anymore so I am wondering where can I get an update version?

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FacebookClient.cs" company="Andrew Arnott">
//     Copyright (c) Andrew Arnott. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

    public class FacebookClient : WebServerClient {
        private static readonly AuthorizationServerDescription FacebookDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription {
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"),
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize"),
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FacebookClient"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public FacebookClient() : base(FacebookDescription) {
            this.AuthorizationTracker = new TokenManager();
        }
    }
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FacebookGraph.cs" company="Andrew Arnott">
//     Copyright (c) Andrew Arnott. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.Text;

    [DataContract]
    public class FacebookGraph {
        private static DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookGraph));

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "link")]
        public Uri Link { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "birthday")]
        public string Birthday { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(string json) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("json");
            }

            return Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
        }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(Stream jsonStream) {
            if (jsonStream == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("jsonStream");
            }
            return (FacebookGraph)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
        }
    }
}


Error   3   The type or namespace name 'OAuth2' does not exist in the namespace 'DotNetOpenAuth' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'WebServerClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'AuthorizationServerDescription' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'DataContractAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'DataContract' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'DataContractJsonSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "newest", you mean CTP3 (4.0.0.11165), you should firstly know that that is known to *not* work with Facebook because Facebook implements an older version of OAuth 2.0.

As far as the build break, it looks like either you're compiling against a DotNetOpenAuth.dll that does not include OAuth 2.0 support. or for some reason the build failed to resolve the reference.  Look for warnings *above* the errors in the build log.

Comment: Newest stable version I guess v3.4.4.

Comment: 3.4.4 isn't the newest stable build; 3.4.7 is.  And it doesn't have a FacebookGraph class in it at all, so that would explain why you're getting the build error.  You seem to be mixing a DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock project from a newer (unreleased) DotNetOpenAuth with an older (released) version of DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: I guess I will stick with the older version of DotNetOpenAuthen till I implement a facebook SDK that can do the account authentication and get rid of the ApplicationBlock.

Comment: Feel free to discard or rip anything out of the ApplicationBlock for your own purposes that you wish.  That's a source distributed project so that you can do *whatever* you want with it.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Hi. Is there any version which works with fw4 and connects to both facebook and google etc ?  Ive been managed (after  hours) to make (this work)[http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLe1e.jpg] but I cant set  the redirect URI. (im using DotNetOpenAuth-4.3.0.13117)

Comment: What is `fw4`? And it looks like you're trying to set the redirect URL *after* you call `ProcessUserAuthorization`, which is pointless because by then you're all done. Instead, you can pass your redirect URL as the second parameter to `RequestUserAuthorization`.